# Linux : how to move and rename the directory if it exist in the target location?

Tags: linux, rename

How to move and automatically rename a `/source/folder` to `/target/folder2` directory if it exist in the target location?

I found discussions about mv, cp, --backup commands to rename files but not for directories if it exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `-d` flag:

```
[ -d folder ] && mv folder folder2
```

Alternatively, you can just ignore the error message of `mv`:

```
mv folder folder2 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my question. I need to automatically rename a folder if it exists in the target location.